# apt-get install and upgrade fails on debian

Tags: linux, debian, apt, aptitude

I've got a strange error preventing me from installing anything on my Debian box.

When I run apt-get upgrade (or apt-get install) it produces this error message:

```
# apt-get upgrade
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

If I do at it tells me - to run `dpkg --configure -a` it produces the following output:

```
# dpkg --configure -a
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.93.4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.26-2-686

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-2.6.26-2-686
dpkg: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

If I do a `df -h /boot` it shows that the partition is almost full:

```
# df -h /boot
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              38M   31M  5.5M  85% /boot
```

If I check the directory it seems that quite a lot of the stuff is duplicated:

```
# ls -la /boot
total 26495
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    1024 2009-11-02 05:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root    4096 2009-10-25 07:46 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   70682 2009-08-20 23:14 config-2.6.18-6-686
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   91690 2009-08-19 11:49 config-2.6.26-2-686
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    1024 2009-09-20 15:48 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4495693 2009-09-20 15:32 initrd.img-2.6.18-6-686
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4495471 2008-12-18 12:50 initrd.img-2.6.18-6-686.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 7175680 2009-09-20 15:54 initrd.img-2.6.26-2-686
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 6239705 2009-09-20 15:48 initrd.img-2.6.26-2-686.bak
drwx------  2 root root   12288 2008-08-29 12:21 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  723580 2009-08-21 05:08 System.map-2.6.18-6-686
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  928010 2009-08-19 11:49 System.map-2.6.26-2-686
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1261508 2009-08-21 05:08 vmlinuz-2.6.18-6-686
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1506032 2009-08-19 11:48 vmlinuz-2.6.26-2-686
```

Can anyone help me get out of this misery? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a stopgap measure, you can remove the .bak files in `/boot`, however I'd really recommend getting a bigger `/boot` partition.  As you've found, 38MB is a bit slim, and the last thing you want to be doing is nuking kernels that you turn out to need.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but isn't expanding the boot partition quite a hazardous task?

Comment: Depends on how your system is setup.  Could be trivial, could be painful.  I'd make sure my backups were solid and then `parted resize` to shrink the partition after `sda1`, use `parted move` to move that partition a little further along the disk, then `parted resize` again to make `sda1` bigger.

Answer (score 3):

What kernel are you currently running? You can check that via `uname -a`. Once you have that information, you can delete the config-, initrd.img-, System.map-, and vmlinuz- files that don't match your current kernel version.

For caution's sake, don't actually delete those files. Rather just copy them to another partition if possible.

Comment: Linux localhost 2.6.18-6-686 #1 SMP Fri Dec 12 16:48:28 UTC 2008 i686 GNU/Linux -- So files with 2.6.18-6 must be kept?

Comment: That's correct. Womble's advice is wise, though, you really need a larger /boot.

Comment: Also sensible to remove the packages which contain them, rather than just vaping the files themselves.

Search for packages containing the files with ``dpkg -S /boot/filename'' and you'll see which one to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is also to make a new /boot partition which would be bigger not to enlarge existing one.